# Why is reflect.runtime.universe.RuntimeClass inferred over Nothing when reflect.runtime.universe._ is present?

Tags: scala, scala-reflect

I've stumbled upon a strange situation where having `reflect.runtime.universe._` imported causes `reflect.runtime.universe.RuntimeClass` to be inferred where it seems `Nothing` would be more appropriate.

Consider this simple method and `List`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def find[A : ClassTag](l: List[Any]): Option[A] =
    l collectFirst { case a: A => a }

val list = List(1, "a", false)
```

I can use it to find the first element in the `List` of some type, and it works well, as expected.

```
scala> find[String](list)
res1: Option[String] = Some(a)

scala> find[Long](list)
res2: Option[Long] = None
```

If I do not supply the type parameter, then `A` is inferred as `Nothing`, so I get `Option[Nothing]`, also as expected.

```
scala> find(list)
res3: Option[Nothing] = None
```

*But*, if I `import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._` and again do not supply the type parameter, `A` is now inferred as `reflect.runtime.universe.RuntimeClass` instead of `Nothing`.

```
scala> find(list)
res4: Option[reflect.runtime.universe.RuntimeClass] = None
                ^ What?
```

This isn't a huge problem, since I can hardly imagine much of a use-case for the `find` method without supplying the type parameter manually, but why does this happen? The `ClassTag` seems partially to blame, as removing it once again causes `Nothing` to be inferred (though completely breaks the method due to erasure). What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like some completely unintended side effect of how the runtime `Universe` is designed internally.

The `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` has type `scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse`.

By importing all its members, you import - in particular - a bunch of implicit `ClassTag` values defined in `scala.reflect.api.ImplicitTags` trait which is extended by the universe.

The `ImplicitTags` trait introduces about 90 different implicit `ClassTag` values. Among them, there is this one:

```
implicit val RuntimeClassTag: ClassTag[RuntimeClass]
```

It looks like the compiler likes it more than others since it decided to use it when inferring arbitrary `ClassTag[A]`. Why is that? This is because `RuntimeClassTag` is *overridden* in `scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse` and implicit values defined in subclasses have priority over implicit values defined in superclasses (as specified somewhere in overloading resolution rules - SLS 6.26.3)

So, summarizing, the compiler inferred `RuntimeClass` for `A` with `ClassTag` context bound because it saw this thing in scope (introduced by wildcard import on universe):

```
trait JavaUniverse extends Universe { self =>
  type RuntimeClass = java.lang.Class[_]
  implicit val RuntimeClassTag: ClassTag[RuntimeClass] = 
    ClassTag[RuntimeClass](classOf[RuntimeClass])
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@ghik's answer is correct, but I think there is one important thing to add. Normally, when we require an implicit `ClassTag[A]`, we expect the compiler to generate the `ClassTag` for us. I was expecting `ClassTag[Nothing]` to be generated when omitting the explicit type parameter. But having the imported `ClassTag[RuntimeClass]` in scope appears to stop that from happening.

We can make this happen by simply introducing another implicit `ClassTag` without importing `runtime.universe._`.

```
scala> implicit val ct = classTag[Long]
ct: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Long] = Long

scala> find(list)
res8: Option[Long] = None
```

The compiler sees that I only have one implicit `ClassTag[Long]` in scope,  so when I call `find(list)`, the compiler assumes *that must be what I wanted* and `A` must be `Long`, because there is no other `ClassTag` available, and it will not generate another `ClassTag` for me.

In the precise context of my question then, I'm importing a boat-load of implicit `ClassTag`s, and the compiler deems that `ClassTag[RuntimeClass]` is the most appropriate of those.